# How to know whether jenkins is up or not using shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins, wget

I have a small query. How to know whether jenkins is up or not using shell script.

Comment: Try
curl -sSf http://jenkins.address.com > /dev/null

Comment: @Radoslaw Grebski : please add that as answer.  OP should accept it as well. Will be useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 curl -sSf jenkins.address.com > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue a **[Jenkins CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI)** command

`java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://www.yourserver.com version`